# UISearchController's search bar overlaps first tableview cell

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, uisearchcontroller

I am using `UISearchController` and the `UISearchBar` also has a scope bar. The search bar is added as a subview to a `UIView` which is above the `UItableView`. I have done it this way since I want the search bar to be always visible even when the tableview is scrolled.

The problem is the scopebar overlaps the first tableview cell

StoryBoard

[image]

Scope bar overlapping the tableview cell

[image]

How can I prevent this overlapping?, I can't display the searchbar in navigationbar since the scopebar when placed in navigation bar does not get displayed.

Comment: you could try setting `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0)` which will push tableView's content 64 points down… you should set that to what ever the size of the scopebar is...

Comment: @chuthan20 Where exactly shall I try setting this, is there a method that is triggered when UISearchController becomes active?

Comment: You could set your view controller to be the delegate of UISearchController, `https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchControllerDelegate_Ref/index.html`

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

Having the Search Display Controller and SearchBar in the tableview header. Add the `heightForHeaderInSection` in your TableViewController.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 44; //I used the 44, the height of SearchBar
}
```

In your case you'll need to also add the scope bar height. 
Now it will always keep a base height.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.searchController.active) {
        return 44; // with scope
    } else {
        return 0; // no scope
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me! For table with sections, when search controller is not active I changed to "return 20; // no scope". Because when is 0, this hides the sections headers.

Answer (score 0):

Add the search bar and table view on the UIViewController as shown in the image below. Don't overlap the search bar with the table view. I am using this in my app and its working fine for me.

[image]

Comment: I was able to get it to work by using `UIEdgeInsetsMake` as suggested in the comments. I have setup exactly like you have done in your image, but that doesn't work